# htmlunit, change of address in the same window

Tags: java, htmlunit

```
    HtmlPage open1 =  (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");

    ScriptResult result = open1.executeJavaScript("window.location.assign('https://www.google.com.tr/search?q'));

    HtmlPage afterExecution = (HtmlPage) result.getNewPage();

    System.out.println(afterExecution); //in window new adres
```

> How do I open a new site in the same window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call `webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com.tr/search?q");`. You don't need to call any javascript.

From the [javadocs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html):

> Convenient method to build an URL and load it into the current
>   WebWindow as it would be done by getPage(WebWindow, WebRequest).